# regex help - ignore /news* but target /new*

Tags: regex

I am a beginner at regex and have the following problem:

I want a regex where it will target only the "**/new**" string and not the "/news" string. Here are two examples of text I want to use it on:

/category/news/new

/category/news/new?t=week

/politics/new

Also, the /news will always precede /new in order. There will also never be another '/' after /new. (I hope that makes sense to you.)

(I use this to apply active classes to the navigation menu. But I get a problem in the news section where the page thinks the active sort type is 'new' when it is actually 'top' as I base this off the URL's path)

I attempted writing one but it didn't work:
/new[^s]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try `/new(?:/|$)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, It's almost right but I left out another use case in my question which I have now added: it needs to also target the /new in the following /category/news/new?t=week

Comment: Then `/new(?:[?/]|$)`

Comment: Thank You Wiktor Stribiżew! This looks to do exactly what I asked for.

Comment: Glad to help, see my answer with a demo and explanation below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/new(?:[?/]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/glox4v/1)

**Details**:

- `/new` -  a literal `/new`  substring
- `(?:[?/]|$)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `[?/]` - either a `?` or  `/`
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string